# Adding new lines to a .txt file

Tags: java, list

I'm studying Chinese.
I have an iPhone app with optical character recognizer that can capture vocab lists in this format: (character TAB pronunciation TAB definition)

> 淫秽  TAB yin2hui4 TAB  obscene; salacious; bawdy
>
> 网站    TAB wang3zhan4 TAB   website
>
> 专项    TAB zhuan1xiang4 TAB     attr. earmarked

but the flashcard app I use requires this format: (Character NEWLINE Pronunciation NEWLINE Definition)

> 淫秽
>
> yin2hui4
>
> obscene; salacious; bawdy
>
> 网站
>
> wang3zhan4
>
> <computing> website
>
> 专项
>
> zhuan1xiang4
>
> attr. earmarked

I only know a little Java. How do I convert the first format to the second format?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a place where programming questions are answered. This is not the place to learn the basic of programming.

Comment: just google it: java reading from files, writing files, etc

Comment: Also I wouldn't choose Java for this task. Perl (or any other scripting language) is far better suited for this.

Comment: those were the keywords I needed (beginner)...thanks

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, we don't want to do your homework. But we don't want to leave you stranded either.

I've left many things open and the below is just a Java-looking pseudocode. You can start here...

```
FileReader reader = ... // open the file reader using the input file
FileWriter writer = ...// open a file for writing output

while(the stream doesn't end) { // provide the condition, as must be
    String line = ... // read a line from the reader
    String character = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("\t")), 
             pronounciation = line.substring(character.length() -1).substring(line.indexOf("\t", character.length()), 
             definition = line.substring(line.lastIndexOf("\t")); // Obviously, this isn't accurate.... you need to work around this. 

    writeLineToFile(character)
    writeLineToFile(pronounciation)
    writeLineToFile(definition)

}

close the reader and writer
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it looks like an Exercise. But ideally you can do.

- Get the file contents (use commons-io)
- Replace TAB with new line and write to file

example code

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

    public class Test {

        /**
         * @param args
         * @throws IOException
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            String path = "C:/test.txt";
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            File file = new File(path);

            String string = FileUtils.readFileToString(file);
            String finalString = string.replaceAll("\t", "\n");
            FileUtils.write(file, finalString);

        }

}
```

The file now would look like

```
    淫秽 
 yin2hui4 
 obscene; salacious; bawdy

    网站 
 wang3zhan4 
 website

    专项 
 zhuan1xiang4 
 attr. earmarked
```

Comment: What if the file's size is a few GB? Would you really want to load the entire file into a `String`?

Comment: He hasn't mentioned that .

Comment: I wasn't the OP, but I'm just suggesting that you could edit your answer to provide the limitations. cheers :)

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't actually say TAB, I just couldn't figure out how to format it correctly...thanks a ton...I was doing this manually like a caveman...this is what i needed:            
            String secondString = string.replaceAll("\n", "\n\n");...
            String finalString = secondString.replaceAll("\t", "\n");...
            FileUtils.write(file, finalString);...as you can see my formatting needs work

Comment: Glad that helped. Accept as answer